# NavigationController size issue

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, uistoryboard

I have a `NavigationController` with a root `ViewController` which in storyboard is the size of an iPhone 6 plus, and one of my test devices is an iPhone 5.

In the `viewDidLoad()` i print out the view height, when testing on iPhone 5 it says that the size is `568` which is the iPhone 5 height... but if I print out the height after a little delay with `dispatch_after()` it says `504`.

I need to have the view for the `ViewController` set to `504` before `viewDidLoad()` gets called.

What could be the problem?

Comment: i am not sure about this but you used loadView() method. it is call before viewDidLoad() method

Comment: @user3736393 where does it say I use loadView()?

Comment: Why do you need to set height before viewDidLoad?